# Procedural material texture scaling

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

Hello everyone people!

I have the following question.

I got a .blend with a ready-made material that I found on Blendswap. This material allows procedural concrete to be applied on random surfaces (this is important because in my current project UV Maps is not an option at all). The material looks very good, but I would like to enlarge the spots of this... uhh... "dirt" let's say (circled red on the picture).

But whatever I try to do with the scaling (circled blue in the Shader editor and green on Right bar), there is no way to get "dirt" grow larger than on a pic. There's some kind of limit, which seems to be about 0.001 or less, that does not allow dirty areas to be larger. If you pass through it, the "dirt" just disappears.

Do you have any idea how to make this "dirt" take up, for example, 90% of the surface or more?

Attaching a file with the material, would be really thankful to hear any ideas.

**Blend file on the link:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a24zb4Bt_qgs2XMxQbHy9p38c-lwPJPY/view?usp=sharing

[image: Related pic]

**UPD:** Marty Fouts' suggestion below works fine, but still not able to pass throug 35% rough and 65% regular surface, the maximum amount of rough area I managed to max out is on the screen. So any ideas to get at lest 50/50?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That "dirt" is the rough area of the concrete generated by this part of the node group:

[image: two Musgrave textures that control the wear]

The way they interact, you have to adjust the color ramp labeled *Huge Wear Mask* as well as the *Detail* and *Dimension* of both textures.

Comment: Yeah, works fine, thanks! But this still isn't the result I'd like to see. There's also some kind of limit not letting tough areas to take up the whole surface. I've tried to max it out and the best proportion I got is probably 35% rough 65% regular surface. Any ideas how to get 50/50 at lest? I'll post a screenshot with my next answer, don't see if I'm able to attach images to comments.

Comment: Edited the OP instead* as moderator advises me.